# Angular ng-file-upload Get Byte Array and FormData in Asp.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ng-file-upload

I am trying to use ng-file-upload to upload files using Angular.  I need the byte array to store in our database (I cannot store the uploaded file on the server), but I also need the FormData as well.  My problem is that I can only seem to get one or the other (either the byte array or the formdata) but not both.

Here is my Angular code:

```
    $scope.uploadPic = function (file) {
    $scope.emrDetailID = 7;
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: '/SSQV4/SSQV5/api/Document/UploadEMRDocument',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { file: file, 'emrdetail': $scope.emrDetailID}
    });
    file.upload.then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
            $scope.imageID = file.result;
        });
    });
};
```

Using the code below, I can get the byte array and store it in my database:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadDocument()
{
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            var f = provider.Contents.First(); // assumes that the file is the only data

            if (f != null)
            {
                string ClientIP = IPNetworking.GetIP4Address();
                var filename = f.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                filename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename).TrimStart('.');
                var buffer = await f.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                FileImageParameterModel pm = new FileImageParameterModel();
                pm.binFileImage = buffer;

                //pm.CompanyID = UserInfo.intMajorID;
                pm.CompanyID = 10707;
                pm.dteDocumentDate = Convert.ToDateTime("4/4/2016");
                pm.dteExpiration = Convert.ToDateTime("4/4/2017");
                pm.vchUserIP = ClientIP;
                pm.vchUploadedbyUserName = UserInfo.Username;
                pm.vchFileExtension = extension;
                CommonClient = new CommonWebApiClient();
                CommonClient.AuthorizationToken = UserInfo.AccessToken;
                int imageID = await CommonClient.InsertNewFileImage(pm);

                return Json(imageID);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Attachment failed to upload");
            }
}
```

Using the code below I can get the FormData

```
                var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(workingFolder);


            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            var emr = provider.FormData["emrdetail"];
```

but then I can't get the byte array as using MultipartFormDataStreamProvider wants a folder to store the file.

There's got to be a way to get both.  I have been searching the internet for 2 days and all I can find are the two solutions above neither of which solves my issue.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking way to complicated. Here is some of my code which I used for file upload in AngularJS with .NET

Angular:

```
   function uploadFileToUrl(file) {
        var formData = new FormData(); // Notice the FormData!!!
        formData.append('uploadedFile', file);

        return $http({
            url: uploadUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        }).then(resolve, reject);

        function resolve(data) {
            $log.debug('data : ', data);
            return data;
        }

        function reject(e) {
            $log.warn('error in uploadFileToUrl : ', e);
            return $q.reject(e);
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
    public Task HandleAsync([NotNull] UploadFilesCommand command)
    {
        return wrapper.InvokeOnChannel(async client =>
        {
            // init command
            command.Output = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            try
            {
                foreach (var file in command.Files)
                {
                    var request = new UploadFileRequest
                    {
                        FileName = file.Name,
                        FileStream = file.Stream
                    };
                    UploadFileResponse response = await client.UploadFileAsync(request);

                    command.Output.Add(file.Name, response.Id);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // dispose streams
                foreach (var file in command.Files)
                {
                    if (file.Stream != null)
                    {
                        file.Stream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a problem understanding your code.  Where are you getting the byte array?  Where is the other formdata?  All I see is the name and the file.  I have to pass other information to my method along with the byte array.